# How can I help Java resolve the types in my RxJava composition method?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I would like to chain two RxJava `Single` instances to create an `Observable` that  emits both of their results. Additionally, I need the result of the first `Single` to create the second.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public static <A extends C, B extends C, C> Observable<C> chain(final Single<A> a, final Function<A, Single<B>> f) {
    return Observable.concat(
        a.toObservable(),
        a.flatMap(f::apply).toObservable());
}
```

Usage might look like this:

```
final Observable<Event> task = MoreObservables.chain(
    writeFile("Hello, world", "hello.txt"),
    writeFileEvent -> processFile(writeFileEvent.path));
```

However, Java complains that it cannot resolve the types:

```
Error:(54, 61) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) A,B,C
(argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
  io.reactivex.Single<ProcessFileEvent> cannot be converted to io.reactivex.Single<Event>)
```

Of course, `ProcessFileEvent` implements `Event`.

How can I write my function so that Java can figure out the types? Or is there an easier way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell why you have compilation error without knowing the exact `writeFile` and `processFile` signatures (from simple simulation it should compile).

anyhow, the more idiomatic way is to use `compose()` method with custom `ObservableTransformer`, in order to have a single chain instead of wrapper methods that makes the chain less readable ([read this](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/)).
there is also logical problem here, as you're using `concat()` and using twice the a `Observable`, you will actually perform the a operation twice (a will be subscribed twice), that can lead to performance issue in the least worst scenario, or to a major subtle bug. (in your example you will write to the same file twice).
I think you should use publish in this case, in order to execute a once, together with merge, this will result with Observable that will emit the result of A, then execute B with result of A, and will emit this result:

The transformer:

```
class PublishAndMergeTransformer<A extends C, B extends C, C> implements ObservableTransformer<A, C> {

        final Function<A, Single<B>> f;

        public PublishAndMergeTransformer(Function<A, Single<B>> f) {
            this.f = f;
        }

        @Override
        public ObservableSource<C> apply(Observable<A> a) {
            return a.publish(aObservable ->
                    Observable.merge(
                            aObservable,
                            aObservable
                                    .flatMap(a1 -> f.apply(a1).toObservable())
                    )
            );
        }
    }
```

and example of use:

```
writeFile("Hello, world", "hello.txt")
    .toObservable()
    .compose(new PublishAndMergeTransformer<>(writeFileEvent -> processFile(writeFileEvent.path)));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and the linked article was very helpful too.